# Modifying data via pointers

Tags: pointers, go, variable-assignment, assignment-operator

https://play.golang.org/p/DOhYaiH53Ek

I do not understand the `*&p` operation nor how a pointer `*p` which is an `int() value NOT a memory address` is able to modify its `value` i.e. `valueX = valueY`. I know that I must be misunderstanding something, but this code literally appears to be self-conflicting.

```
//point

package main

import "reflect"

var pt int = 27

func main() {
    println(reflect.TypeOf(pt))
    println("pt = ", pt)   //value of pt
    println("&pt = ", &pt) //memory address of pt
    updatePointer(&pt)
    println("pt = ", pt) //value of pt
}

func updatePointer(p *int) { //requires memory address of an int
    println("&p = ", &p)                                //memory address of p
    println("p = ", p)                                  //memory address of pt
    println("*p before = ", *p)                         //value of pt
    println(*p == 27)                                   //true
    *p = 14                                             //27 = 14??????????
    println("*p =", *p)                                 //value of pt
    println(reflect.TypeOf(&pt) == reflect.TypeOf(*&p)) //true!!!?????
    println("*&p = ", *&p)                              //memory address which p's memory address evals to???? 0x800 (p) -> 0x900 (pt) = 0x800 (p)?
}

/*
Why can't I do the following?

func updatePointer(p *int){
    p = 14
    //OR
    &p = 14
    //OR
    *&p = 14
}
*/
```

Answer (score 2):

Simplify. For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

func f(q *int) {
    fmt.Println(*q, q, &q, "f")
    *q = 14
    fmt.Println(*q, q, &q, "f")
}

func main() {
    var i int = 27
    var p *int = &i
    fmt.Println(*p, p, &p, i, "main")
    f(p)
    fmt.Println(*p, p, &p, i, "main")
}
```

Output:

```
27 0x40e020 0x40c138 27 main
27 0x40e020 0x40c148 f
14 0x40e020 0x40c148 f
14 0x40e020 0x40c138 14 main
```

Errors:

```
/*
func g(r *int) {
    // cannot use 14 (type int) as type *int in assignment
    r = 14
    // cannot assign to &r
    &r = 14
    // cannot use 14 (type int) as type *int in assignment
    *(&r) = 14
}
*/
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/Hwe3anFBTfD

---

In Go, all arguments are passed by value, as if by assignment. A pointer `p` to an int `i` is passed by value (`q = p`) to function `f`. The pointer `q`, a copy of `p`, is used to modify the value of `i`, `*q = 14`, `*q` dereferences type `*int` to type `int`.

---

The function `g` compiler error messages explain why the statements are illegal. For example, `*&r = 14` is `*(&r) = 14` is `r = 14`, `cannot use 14 (type int) as type *int in assignment`, `r` is type `*int`.

---

References:

[A Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org)

[The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)

Answer (score 2):

Considering `*&p` firstly lets simplify the example (removing all of the irrelevant stuff)

```
var pt int = 27
p := &pt // because &pt is passed as the argument into updatePointer
*p = 14  // This assigns 14 to whatever p points to (i.e. pt)
println(reflect.TypeOf(&pt) == reflect.TypeOf(*&p))
```

`*&` does nothing (and I can see no reason to use it in a real application); the statement gets the address of p (the `&p` bit) and then gets what the result points at (`p`). So this an be rewritten

```
println(reflect.TypeOf(&pt) == reflect.TypeOf(p))
```

`p` is pointing to `pt` so `p == &pt` (by definition this means that `*p == pt`). This means they are the same thing so will, of course, have the same type.

So why does `*p = 14` work? You said that "*p which is an int() value NOT a memory address is able to modify its value" but that is not quite what [the spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Address_operators) says:

> For an operand x of pointer type *T, the pointer indirection *x
>   denotes the variable of type T pointed to by x. If x is nil, an
>   attempt to evaluate *x will cause a run-time panic.

So what `*p = 14` is saying is set the variable that p points to to 14.

Now lets look at your second question:

```
// Why can't I do the following?

func updatePointer(p *int){
    p = 14
    //OR
    &p = 14
    //OR
    *&p = 14
}
```

So p is a pointer to an integer (thats what `*int` means). Saying `p = 14` is an attempt to set the pointer (not the int) to the value 14. 14 is an int not a pointer hence the compiler error `cannot use 14 (type int) as type *int in assignment`.

`&p = 14` is saying set the address of p to 14. `p` is a `*int` so getting the address will give you a `**int` (a pointer to a pointer to an int). The compiler error you will get is `cannot assign to &p` and this is because the result of `&p` is not [addressable](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Address_operators). You could get around that by saying

```
x := &p
x = 14
```

and this will give you the error you might expect based upon what I said above: `cannot use 14 (type int) as type **int in assignment`.

`*&p = 14` is basically the same as saying `p=14` (it gets the address of p and then gets whatever the result points at whis will be p).

Pointers can get quite confusing (especially in contrived examples) and [this article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pointers-in-golang/) may help you understand.